# My files on micro SD card not showing on macbook pro 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, sd-card

Used to work fine. Could it be a virus from Window PC, I can't see my photos on SD card on mac. Is there any way to copy these views.

I know I can try it on Windows PC and that might work but I don't have access to one right now. BTW it shows only one file in the card, named

> NIKON001.DSC

My camera is Nikon.

Comment: Is the card partitioned?